# Rendering images file to html page with moustache, enlive and Clojure

Tags: html, clojure, jetty, ring, enlive

In my application with moustache (a micro framework to to wire Ring handlers and middlewares), enlive (as html template engine), and clojure, I can't view the images in my html file. How to render these file to html?

Answer (score 3):

If you have your files locally, make sure Ring has a route that maps to your images.

This the doc for the needed method: [API for middleware.file](http://mmcgrana.github.com/ring/middleware.file-api.html)

And then make sure you have something like this in your routes:

```
(def routes
  (app
    (wrap-file "resources")
     ..))
```

Comment: Will you please give me the full method? my static file are in the wap directory within the project src directory!

Comment: what are the routes of your application ? and where are your files located  ?